# Dart list get the longest string

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get first longest string ? How can i do this ?

```
List<String> list = ['hi', 'hello', 'frozen', 'big mistake', 'cool daddy'];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is the shortest solution, which will return the longest string:

```
list.reduce((a, b) {
   return a.length > b.length ? a : b;
})
```

another alternative is:

```
list.sort((a, b) {
   return b.length - a.length;
});
print(list[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the below function i have done in my project to get the longest string.

```
long_string(arr) {
        var longest = arr[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].length > longest.length) {
                longest = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return longest;
    }
```

And you can call the function like below to get the longest string

```
var arr = ["Orebro", "Sundsvall", "Hudriksvall", "Goteborgsdsdsds"];
  print(long_string(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by Sparko Sol could also be used in an extension on `List<String>` to make it easier to reuse this method anywhere in the codebase. Such an extension could look something like

```
extension Longest on List<String> {
  /// Returns the longest element in a [List<String>]
  String longest() {
    return reduce((a, b) {
      return a.length > b.length ? a : b;
    });
  }
}
```

Then, to use this extension, you could simply write something like

```
String longestString = list.longest();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
final longestString = list.fold<String>('', 
  (previousValue, element) => 
    element.length > previousValue.length ? element : previousValue)
```